# GLMM for continuous response in $[0, 1]$

Tags: r, normality-assumption, glmm, glmmtmb

I am looking into GLMMs because my linear model residuals' plot has a weird pattern (some residuals form a diagonal pattern), and a lack of normality was also confirmed with a Shapiro test. Furthermore, I have multiple responses from each participant and for that reason I believe I need a mixed model. My response variable is continuous in $[0,1]$. It is an evaluation from "negative" to "positive" given on a slider.

The independent variables are: a 3-level categorical variable (the levels are positive, neutral, negative), age, gender, the number of trial (for detecting habituation due to more exposure into the stimulus).

What would be an appropriate model? I tried `glmmTMB` with beta family in R, but it doesn't accept $0$ and $1$ in the response. If there is a simpler way to solve my problem, I would be interested since I am worried that even if I end up using the appropriate GLMM, I would face a big challenge with the interpretation of the results.

I am working with R so please point me to particular functions when this is possible.

Comment: Can you describe your variables? The best option is contingent on details you have not yet provided.

Comment: I added a description of the independent variables in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider a zero and one inflated Beta mixed-effects model. If we denote your outcome by $Y$, this will be the combination of a multinomial regression for $\{Y = 0\}$, $\{Y \in (0, 1)\}$ and $Y = 1$, and a Beta model for the middle part.

This is model available in the [**brms**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=brms) package in R; for more info check [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_families.html#zero-inflated-and-hurdle-models).

Comment: I checked the package and read a bit about Bayesian statistics to familiarize. How can I tell if my model is good? I did not get any warnings after several efforts. Bulk_ESS and Rhat look reasonable according to specifications. But the pp_check plot shows that the posterior simulations deviate a lot from the observed. Does this mean that the prior I used  with `get_prior()` is not good? Or maybe the family `zero_one_inflated_beta(link = "logit", link_phi = "log", link_zoi = "logit", link_coi = "logit")` is the problem?